# Make current div responsive

Tags: html, responsive, flash

I have tried for some time to make this box responsive. Look at [my webpage](http://xn--stergaardpagels-4tb.dk/dkc/test.html). The problem shows when the flash player is smaller then 480 x 299.

I got the videos from [restudy](https://portal.restudy.dk/video/line%C3%A6r-sammenh%C3%A6ng/id/52/versionId/2293/educationCategoryId/2) which is a danish site for studying math. Im trying to embed it to my website but the video doesnt resize with the panel.

```
   <div id="res_videoplayer717658626d64706355777035365a424a69434f4355673d3d#595a35567868612f2f2f5634554370307461315962773d3d#0_div" autostart="off"  player_size="small" class="res_videoplayer_div"></div>
```

I tried to add another id for the div, but that didnt work either. Any suggestions?

My whole code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../bower_components/respond/dest/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row topcontrol">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">

          <div id="res_videoplayer717658626d64706355777035365a424a69434f4355673d3d#595a35567868612f2f2f5634554370307461315962773d3d#0_div" autostart="off"  player_size="small" class="res_videoplayer_div"></div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">

          <div id="res_videoplayer717658626d64706355777035365a424a69434f4355673d3d#595a35567868612f2f2f5634554370307461315962773d3d#0_div" autostart="off"  player_size="small" class="res_videoplayer_div"></div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    

  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.restudy.dk/scripts/addvideo.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make it responsive in what way exactly?  Prevent it from shrinking or make the videos resize

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @William yes exacly make the videos resize.

Comment: @j08691 I have tried to update the text now. Is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately because the iframes are not on the same domain(https://restudy.dk/ vs http://xn--stergaardpagels-4tb.dk/dkc/test.html)  and because the embedded video didn't use 100% width and 100% height there is no way to do what you want to accomplish.